# Unable to access Jupyter notebook in the web browser

Tags: python, docker, port, jupyter-notebook, tensorflow-serving

I am running a docker container and I need to connect to Jupyter notebook's web application on my browser. I have installed the Jupyter notebooks and on executing the command "jupyter notebook --port 6006" for running the notebook, the following message is displayed:

[image]

The docker inspect command states the following:

```
"Ports":{
      "6006/tcp":null,
      "8888/tcp":null
}
```

However, on opening the Jupyter web application in Chrome using "http://192.168.99.102:6006/", an error is displayed stating the 'site cannot be reached'. Could someone help me in connecting the Jupyter notebook web application.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried entering `localhost:8888` in the address bar?

Comment: @R.S.NikhilKrishna The notebook is on `8810`